# Как сверстать данный блок используя только html и css?

Tags: html, css

Я не про в css, мне нужно сверстать данный блок. Интересует именно, как сделать эти треугольники[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучший вариант, какой приходит на ум это использовать svg маски. Тут подробнее https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй через svg

```html
<svg width="160" height="140" viewBox="0 0 160 140" fill="none">
        <path 
            d="M71.3397 5C75.1887 -1.66666 84.8113 -1.66667 88.6603 5L157.942 125C161.791 131.667 156.98 140 149.282 140H10.718C3.01997 140 -1.79129 131.667 2.05771 125L71.3397 5Z" 
            fill="#D9D9D9"
        />
    </svg>
```

А картинку вставь уж через css